# How to train a specific font

Tags: tesseract

I'd like to use tesseract to recognize digits on gas meters. I have an image:

[image]

If I try to recognize this image using "tesseract gas.png output", it gives me "Empty page!!" and the output is empty. I started with training using this tutorial: https://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301
I tried to take one letter and train tesseract with this letter:

[image]

I tried this command "tesseract eng.matrx60x40.exp0.png output -psm 10" which worked ("2" in output.txt). I followed the tutorial and I get final eng.traineddata.

[eng.traineddata](http://temp.circlegate.com/zbynda/test/eng.traineddata)

If I now try to use this traineddata with command "tesseract gas.png output" on the original image, I get "Empty page!!".
Am I doing anything wrong, or it is not possible to train the tesseract letter by letter?